# MS Graph groups API : Request_ResourceNotFound when only filtering on id

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-api

When I send this query to Graph:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=id eq '8bd1ac2d-7cbf-4316-8f5d-0819179f4cff'
```

And the group exists, I get an array with 1 group.

But the same query with an id that does not exist, I get this error : Request_ResourceNotFound
How come I don't get an empty array ?
How should I test if the group exists without getting an error ? I work in Power Automates.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the empty array as the result of graph API if the group id is not exist.

Its always return the **Request_ResourceNotFound."Resource 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."**,

For workaround you can use the [List groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph API to get the list of groups.
And then compare the group id in the list.